# hover em imagem utilizando bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-hover

Estou tentando aplicar um efeito com hover, porém não estou conseguindo. Estou utilizando bootstrap 4. Eu consegui realizar o que quero ou quase isso, o problema é que aparece abaixo e não sobre a imagem.

**Segue o código:**

```css
  .texto{
                padding:20px;
                font-family:Arial;
                text-align:center;
                color:white;
                opacity:0;
                transition: opacity .2s linear;
                background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
            }

            .imagem:hover .texto{
                opacity:1;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>teste</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
        
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="all">Exibir todos</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="1">Granitos</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="2">Quartzo</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="3">Mármores importados</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="4">Superfície artificiais</button>
        
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
      
        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->
        
        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="gallery" id="gallery">
        
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2 imagem">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="texto"><h2>teste</h2></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
        
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Vertical/mountain1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
        
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Vertical/mountain2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
        
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
        
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
        
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Vertical/mountain3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->
            
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 3">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 3">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 3">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

            <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var selectedClass = "";
                $(".filter").click(function(){
                selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
                $("#gallery").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
                $("#gallery div").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('animation');
                setTimeout(function() {
                $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('animation');
                $("#gallery").fadeTo(300, 1);
                }, 300);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Queria que ao posicionar/passar o mouse por cima da imagem, aparecesse o texto, só que, como já mencionei, o texto aparece abaixo e não acima.

**P.S.:** Não cheguei a redimensionar a imagem para postar aqui, por considerar que isso seja irrelevante para o entendimento da pergunta.

Comment: dar down vote sem dizer qual o motivo?

Comment: Lucas, você só colou todo o seu código. Não poderia diminuir o ruído e postar só o que interessa? Já adianto que me parece que você não soube sobrepor texto e imagem por falta de conhecimento de CSS. Dê uma olhada sobre como fazer isso com `position: absolute` e `position: relative`. PS: o downvote não é meu

Comment: @fernandosavio concordo com vc, position nesse caso é o mais fácil de se aplicar mesmo. Sobre o downvote, não vi muito motivo, pecar por explicar a mais ou colocar código além do suficiente para simular o problema é melhor do que não colocar código algum...

Comment: @fernandosavio se o cara dizer o por qual motivo deu down vote, tudo bem! Eu não nasci sabendo, o cara que faz isso certamente sim, só pode, porém se alguém der voto negativo e não dizer onde estou errando (não digo no código e sim nas perguntas), eu não saberei corrigir, simplesmente isso, crítica sem feedback. Valeu pelo comentário, vou editar a minha pergunta.

Comment: Lucas, é chato receber downvote mas não te abala, as vezes é injusto mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara tem várias formas de alinhar isso, mas apenas com as classes do BS4 vc consegue resolver praticamente tudo, vc precisa principalmente coloca a classe `card-img-overlay` no container do texto, e colocar a classe `position-relative` no container pai, depois com as classes helpers de Flex do próprio BS4 vc centraliza tudo. Aqui vc pode consultar a documentação https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#image-overlays

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.texto {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s linear;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.imagem:hover .texto {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Grid column -->
<div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2 imagem position-relative">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="texto card-img-overlay position-absolute d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h2>teste</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Apenas com classes do BS4**

O Bootstrap 4, dentro do componente do CARD tem uma opção de Card-Overlay, onde vc consegue colocar um texto por cima da imagem. Se vc quiser colocar o texto da forma que quer, sem muito CSS extra, vc pode partir desse modelo.

```css
.card:hover .card-img-overlay {
  display:flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
                <img class="card-img w-100" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-none justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Já vou deixar a dica de não atribuir valor ao `top`, assim a caixa de texto fica com o tamanho natural que ela deveria ter.

Comment: Tava vendo a documentação e vou deixar aqui o link pois o Bootstrap já vem com [classes helper pra position](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/#common-values).

Comment: @fernandosavio sim tem position nos helpres, só estou avaliando como alinhar, mas deve ser possível. estou testando, valeu a dica ;)

Comment: @fernandosavio olha o que tem justamente dentro da classe nativa do BS4  para fazer o overlay :D http://prntscr.com/p8e7rf

Comment: @hugocsl cara, eu estou tentando fazer igual você fez acima, porém não estou conseguindo. Notei que vocÊ está utilizando outra versão da jQuery e do Bootstrap, será isso?

Comment: Putz... não é que tem mesmo!? [Olha aí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#image-overlays)!

Comment: @fernandosavio sim sim, tinha citado esse link na resposta rss

Comment: @LucasInácio cara nada tem a ver com jQuery, repare na minha resposta que nem jQuery eu indexei no snippet com o código da minha resposta. É tudo com CSS e o jQuery ou qq outro JS não tem sentido atrapalhar a formatação. Deve ter outro CSS que vc fez te atrapalhando

Comment: onde posso mandar o css da galeria completo?

Comment: Publica no CodePen ou https://jsfiddle.net/ mas tente fazer um modelo insolado, só em uma imagem, sem a galeria, para ver se vc entende melhor o que foi feito, e se funciona certinho. Tira outros css que vc fez n mão ou coisa do tipo, pois só com o CSS do BS fica tudo certinho... como vc pode ver ai aciima

Comment: vou fazer isso, porém preciso que funcione com a galeria.

Comment: Putz que animal, não vi.. hauehauehua

Comment: @hugocsl acabei fazendo na mão mesmo, foi mais custoso, mas creio que ficou bem mais bonito e customizado. Por outro lado, vlw pelas dicas que, acabei utilizando em outro lugar do projeto. abs!

Comment: @LucasInácio fico feliz em ter ajudado, obrigado pela força, abs